# Why does my while loop not stop when used in a function?

Tags: python

Okay so I either don't understand the code in the other questions, or my question is different.
Here's my code:

```
    import random, math, sys, time

    userinput = 0

    while "quit" != userinput:

        def lol():
            global userinput, why
            why = userinput = input("What the heck are you doing? ")
            print(why, userinput)
            lol()

        lol()

        why = userinput = input("Type: ")
```

When I type "quit" in the "Type:" the program quits. However, when I type "quit" in my function, it keeps going. Why is this?

Comment: why are you defining a function in a loop?

Comment: You never call `lol()`, the line where you try to is indented too much.

Comment: Is that not possible? If it's not, am I that stupid?

Comment: It's possible, just not needed. But you're trying to call lol inside the function definition.

Comment: Alexander I know, I removed it. But whenever I call it, it won't stop.

Comment: I know it's not needed but I was trying this so I could use it in other ways.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that's generally bad practice.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into Ipython, and it quit when I typed "quit", so I'm not sure what you're doing.

Comment: Assuming you call `lol()` from somewhere within the loop. Your function is iterative, and it does not `return`, so it never exits the function to do the `while` test.

Comment: Scatter some print *statements* around to see what might be happening.

Comment: Type "quit" 1000 times and I promise it **will** quit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks extremely weird. Also you actually have function inside a loop not the other way around.

You also have the function lol pointing back to itself so it will keep repeating forever.

Cleared up the code for you, also deleted the "why" you can add the globalizations back if u need them.

```
def lol():
    userinput = 0
    while "quit" != userinput:
        userinput = input("What are you doing? ")
        print(userinput)
lol()
```

Comment: *"it will keep repeating forever"* - Wrong. Only until the maximum recursion depth is exceeded, at which point it will crash.

Comment: you wanna start talking about "perpetual motion machines" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Once inside the lol function, it just loops. Whatever you enter there never gets tested to see if it equals "quit".

So the answer to your question becomes clear once you follow the program flow: presumably you call the lol function from somewhere in the loop, and then that function calls itself, no matter what you enter there. The function iterates endlessly.